# A last-seen time label added to questions to foster OP votes and accepts?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, user-card

On several SE sites, a recurring issue is a low rate of upvoted or accepted answers by the OP. Some just pop up for a question, reappear in the SE site seldomly, and do not bother marking answers appropriately.

If I understand concerns about the "last-seen" time label regarding spying at work, once the last-seen date exists on the profile page, I wonder whether this information  could appear close to, or be added  to the "asked" information below the question:

[image: Last seen]

Such a last-seen mark could be a good incentive to remind OP to vote for answers to your own question, and could tell people who answered whether the OP really is interested in promoting good answers... or not.

Comment: Why would a more public "last-seen mark" be an incentive of anything? How would it remind the OP to do anything?

Comment: First, the OP will know that the readers know, as well, the last time he logged on. Somebody who asks and seldom votes could be more apparent. Second, when no answer has be accepted for a long time, one of those who answered, or moderators, could benefit from a recent visit of the OP to gently ask whether the answers were satisfactory.

Comment: There's absolutely no requirement for people to accept answers. And there's absolutely nothing wrong if they choose not to do so.

Comment: I asked this in the spirit of incentives and reminders, and not about moral obligations, wrongs or "shoulds".

Comment: A (very infrequent) automated reminder already exists. Anything else - especially if it's in the sphere of shaming people ("the OP will know that the readers know...") to accept answers - is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Yannis This information is already a click away to the OP profile. Just making it more accessible

Comment: I understand that. I just don't see any benefit in making it more accessible. There's already an incentive to accept answers (the +2 rep reward), and there's already a reminder. What is the problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: I will ask people on the sites I usually visit to have a feedback. Basically, when a question is answered, and at least one answer seems good, and not accepted, and one sees the OP does not come back, there is little incentive to improve the answers. If one sees the OP came back, he can interact (via comments) to check what should be improved. Instead of letting each visitor click the OP page, having it visually  apparent could be more direct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morally no. Logically no.

It doesn't take much time and effort to select the OP's profile and see for yourself the last time they were on SE. Anyways, the OP may not even have the privilege to vote *up* (10 rep). Thus forcing the OP to vote is definitely not a good idea, especially when they prefer not to for their own reasons. Users should only vote when they want to, not when they are under constant peer pressure because of this feature.

Anyways, if the OP isn't going to return for a long time, it is more likely the OP won't even realize there is such a feature. Unfortunately, most new users don't quite understand a lot of SE at first (struggles to deal with downvotes, what in the world is the accept, I have a profile page?!!) so a small feature like this will probably go unnoticed for now.

The above makes the logical sense of me say no. Now here comes the morals-ish part. As stated above, peer pressure isn't acceptable. Especially when it comes down to that nice upvote and that all so precious accept. Users have said for ages, ***DO NOT FORCE OTHERS TO UPVOTE OR ACCEPT ANSWERS*** (the all-caps is just for emphasis). Now to deal with your counter-arguments (yes I am quite thorough with this answer):

> Basically, when a question is answered, and at least one answer seems good, and not accepted, and one sees the OP does not come back, there is little incentive to improve the answers.

You can receive badges for editing other users' answers (don't edit or do anything just for the badges) passively, users do appreciate editors, and did you forget the hundreds to thousands to maybe millions of users that can view and vote on the answers? The accept shows the OP's favorite answer. The vote count technically help show the community's favorite answer... ish.

So why do we answer in the first place? To answer the OP's problem and hopefully others. And when it does appropriately, users can receive positive feedback from the community through voting, bounties, and comments. So incentive isn't a problem. Anyways, we do have Tenacious and Unsung Hero for those left behind...

> ...could tell people who answered whether the OP is interested in promoting good answers or not.

If you are answering a question, you have to make a good, nice-quality answer to be positively received by the community and the OP. You shouldn't be lazy and create a short, non-detailed answer. The OP anyways isn't here to promote good answers, the OP is here to *receive* good answers because that is a reason why you join a Q/A site in the first place.